# I make billions

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I make billions,
I never spend less than $1000,
I'm a man in black,
I'm a force of nature,
I'm the original,
Audiences of all ages have seen me.

Who / what am I?

Comment: Bill Gates.....OR .....Microsoft ????

Comment: Sorry not Bill Gates or Microsoft.  I added the wordplay tag to this.  When you see the answer I think it will make sense (hopefully).  I didn't want to make it too easy so some of the lines are a bit vague on their own but make sense on the whole.  If this is too hard I have hints in mind that will help.  This is my first riddle, and I thought people would get it right away.   We'll see how long it takes.

Comment: Is it rot13(Jnyg Qvfarl)?

Comment: @Adam No sorry.  More wordplay, less literal.

Comment: @JS1 Great riddle!  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hopefully someone can finish this:

> G=giga = affix for times 10^9
>  G=grand = 1000 dollars
>  G-man = government (FBI) agent
>  G=constant for the force of gravity
>  OG=original gangsta (slang term meaning "the original" or "old-school")
>  G=general audience viewing = movie rating

Comment: I think you've probably got it. I imagine "the original" is probably referring to [(spoiler)](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/og/).

Comment: Wow, right after I saw the answer, I was thinking rot13(Vg'f BT!) *Then looks down at comments*

Comment: God is the missing item in your answer.

Comment: @Overmind - I'm not aware of 'G' being used to mean God, but God is a missing item in all answers ;)

Comment: The missing answer is what Alconja and Duck guessed in the comments.

Comment: @JS1 - I'm not familiar with that 'OG' (although I've heard of various rappers called 'G' = ? Grand Master ?).  I would have preferred a clue about the musical note 'G'.  Feel free to edit my answer and I'll approve if it is explained.

Comment: @amI I had quite a few other clues in mind but I thought that the more clues I gave, the easier the riddle would be.  So I kept the riddle somewhat short.  As for OG, it's a slang term that is probably not well known outside the U.S.

Comment: @JS1 - Ah, I see that (spoiler) G=Gangsta, and the rap is called G-funk, and there is some claim to being the Original Gangsta, but 'OG' is not a good answer as it breaks the 'G' pattern.

Comment: and there's Ice-T: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O.G._Original_Gangster; @amI

Comment: @JonMarkPerry - yes, but is he called 'G' (rather than 'OG')? -- or should he be saved for a puzzle based on 'T'?

Comment: @amI; probably, but God isn't renowned for wearing black either :)

Comment: @JS1 "Who / what am I?" Refer to OG?

Comment: @shinjo What am I?  Answer is the letter "G".