# I make billions (#2)

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> #### I make billions (#2)
>
> - At 9, I met my best friend,
> - At 12, I lived an outdoor life,
> - At 13, I broke my arm right before camp,
> - At 15, I worked my first corporate job,
> - At 17, I was separated from my father,
> - At 18, I changed my name to keep my identity private,
> - At 20, I bought my first of three sports cars,
> - At 21, I became the owner of a French restaurant,
> - At 22, I invested heavily in robotics,
> - At 23, I wound up travelling to South America,
> - At 24, I reconnected with all of my childhood friends,
> - At 25, I did a driving tour through Japan, Italy, and England,
> - At 26, I lived in Scotland and had a magical time,
> - At 27, I researched child psychology at a university,
> - At 29, I had mixed emotions about moving to San Francisco,
> - At 30, I reunited with my parents after a long separation,
> - At 31, I discovered my spiritual side,
> - At 32, I took time off to raise my three incredible children,

Who / What am I?

Hint 1:

> I'm 33 years old (as of 2019).

(Previous ["I make billions" riddle is here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85513/i-make-billions))

Comment: rot13(Znlor Qbevf Svfure?)

Comment: @Duck No it isn't.  Like the other billions riddle, I think this one will make sense once you see the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is:

> **Pixar** 
> These ages are directly related to the release dates of various Pixar feature films. The desrpitions that follow are quick snippets of the main plot for each. And, most obviously, Pixar has made billions of dollars over the years.

Age 9:

> Toy Story

Age 12:

> A Bug's Life

Age 13:

> Toy Story 2

Age 15:

> Monsters, Inc.

Age 17:

> Finding Nemo

Age 18:

> The Incredibles

Age 20:

> Cars

Age 21:

> Ratatoullie

Age 22:

> WALL-E

Age 23:

> Up

Age 24:

> Toy Story 3

Age 25:

> Cars 2

Age 26:

> Brave

Age 27:

> Monsters University

Age 28:

> Inside Out

Age 30:

> Finding Dory

Age 31:

> Coco

Age 32:

> Incredibles 2

Comment: I make billions...

Comment: @zeethreepio Was there a particular one that gave it away?  I was afraid someone would get it right away so I made it hard on purpose.  But later I edited some of the clues to make it a bit easier.

Comment: @JS1 For some reason the age 22 and age 23 clues together sparked something in my head and it just clicked. It had me stumped for most of the day though. Good puzzle!