# I make billions (#3)

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay, rhyme

> #### I make billions (#3)
>
> My products are quite edgy,
>   But most have been a bust,
>   I'm only one of many,
>   Lord knows who we can trust,
>
> I'm not a politician,
>   Yet I work with presidents,
>   And like a mathematician,
>   I seek proofs of excellence,
>
> I resemble a detective,
>   Who fills in all the blanks,
>   And if gold is your objective,
>   I've more than all the banks,
>
> Who / what am I?

Hint for line 3:

> Lines 3 and 4 are two sides of the same coin.

<sub>Previous riddles:

[I make billions #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85513/i-make-billions)

[I make billions #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85557/i-make-billions-2)</sub>

Comment: To those trying to solve: the answer by Showsni is mostly correct but missing explanations for lines 3, 4, 11-12.  I modified line 12 to make it more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s

> The US Mint(s)

My products are quite edgy,

> Coins have edges

But most have been a bust,

> They have busts of politicians

I'm only one of many,

> In the US the coins say “E Pluribus Unum”, meaning “Out of Many, One”. Thanks to @postmortes!

Lord knows who we can trust,

> In the US the coins say “In God We Trust”

I'm not a politician,

> Mints aren’t politicians

Yet I work with presidents,

> Presidents have their likenesses on coins

And like a mathematician, 
I seek proofs of excellence,

> Per @JonMark Perry, a proof is a non-legal tender coin made pre-release in order to check the die for flaws

I resemble a detective, 
Who fills in all the blanks,

> A blank is a coin that hasn’t yet been stamped

And if gold is your objective, 
I've more than all the banks,

> The US Federal Reserve stores its gold bullion reserve in [4 Mint locations around the US](https://www.bullionstar.com/blogs/ronan-manly/gold-bullion-stored-us-mint-denver/) including at Fort Knox, a US Mint with nearly 5000 tonnes of gold. Goldfinger famously went after Fort Knox rather than any bank when he was looking to steal gold from the US.

Comment: Correct answer, but the explanation for line 3 and lines 11-12 are wrong.  Check the puzzle because I made some edits and added a hint.  Also for line 7 I had a different meaning of proof in mind.  You can look it up.  You are the closest so far.

Comment: A 'proof coin' is a coin made pre-release, so to check the die for flaws, and not legal currency. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_coinage

Comment: @JS1 how does this look?

Comment: Line 3 -- it looks like this is specifically US money, so "E pluribus unum" is written on their coins, I believe

Comment: @postmortes — excellent catch!! Updated with your great suggestion!

Comment: Looks great!  Solution complete!

Answer (score 5):

You're a

> Mint. Coins have edges, and generally a bust of the monarch. American money generally has presidents on it, and proof coins are struck to check for excellence. Coins are made from blanks, and mints often use gold.

Comment: Yes, you have it for the most part but there is some more.  Lines 3 and 4 have a meaning.  Also the last line has a bit more meaning than what you said.  These lines are where the "knowledge tag" come into play.  They also point to a specific instance of your answer and not just any one.

Comment: Maybe "rot13(va tbq jr gehfg)" on the fourth line implies the rot13(H.F. Zvag)

Comment: rot13(r cyhevohf hahz), guys.

Answer (score 2):

Going off the comment on the other answer, I believe you are a

> U.S. dollar bill.

My products are quite edgy, But most have been a bust,

> There have been many types of paper currency, a lot of which have been [discontinued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banknotes_of_the_United_States_dollar).

I'm only one of many,

> There are many bills now, both in sheer number and in denominations.

Lord knows who we can trust,

> Dollar bills have "In God we trust" printed on them.

I'm not a politician, Yet I work with presidents,

> Most dollar bills have presidents on them (they are even sometimes called after the president depicted on them).

And like a mathematician, I seek proofs of excellence,

> Not exactly sure here? I think proof bills are printed to check for 'excellence'?

I resemble a detective, Who fills in all the blanks,

> Not exactly sure here? I was thinking maybe slang terms, but I'm drawing a blank. (pun intended)

And if gold is your objective, I've more than many banks,

> Dollar bills used to be banknotes, which were issued by individual banks rather than the Federal Reserve. Also, they used to be [Gold Certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_certificate), where you could trade in the certificate for actual gold with the issuer.

Comment: The answer by Showsni is mostly correct but missing explanations for lines 3, 4, 7-8.  You explained 4 correctly.

Comment: I meant 11-12 not 7-8, sorry.  So lines 3, 11-12.

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking off many other answers, but I think this fits a little better.

I believe you are

> A U.S. penny

My products are quite edgy,
But most have been a bust

> An incredible number of US pennies have been made.

I'm not a politician,
Yet I work with presidents

> Lincoln is on the face of the penny, at the point.

And like a mathematician,
I seek proofs of excellence,

> Coins are checked to be of the highest quality/excellence.

I resemble a detective,
Who fills in all the blanks,

> Pennies often act to "fill in blanks" because they are the lowest denomination of currency.

And if gold is your objective,
I've more than many banks,

> Banks always keep many rolls of pennies in handy.

Comment: To those trying to solve: the answer by Showsni is mostly correct but missing explanations for lines 3, 4, 11-12.