# I make billions (#4)

Tags: riddle, rhyme, lateral-thinking, limerick

> #### I make billions (#4)
>
> For years did a sharp little verse,
>   Grow fast in our ears like a curse,
>   A tune on TV,
>   Did subconsciously,
>   Cause all to spend much from their purse,
>
> Who / what am I?

Previous riddles in this series:

[I make billions #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85513/i-make-billions)
[I make billions #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85557/i-make-billions-2)
[I make billions #3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85634/i-make-billions-3)

Comment: Just to confirm: is this even remotely solvable by someone living outside the US?

Comment: I looked it up and this should be known in 120 countries and 20 languages (according to wikipedia)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After substituting inventive googling for youtube videos for my lack of TV savviness, I'm pretty sure this Billion Maker is

> McDonald's.

The poem's solution is clearly something along the lines of

> advertising jingle

and then there's the

> acrostic "F-G-A-D-C", which seems to be the ["I'm Loving It" jingle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GApPXZAvkRI)'s tune.

Comment: @JS1 given that the video I linked to starts with TV examples of the tune in at least 5 different keys, one of which is exactly the one given, I'm really not sure the "sharp" verse needs to have anything to do with it.

Comment: I guess maybe I didn't do enough research because I thought there was only one key.  You have some impressive googling / youtubing skills btw!  I need to make these harder too, you got it very fast!