# I make billions (#5)

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

> #### I make <s>bullions</s> <s>balloons</s> billions (#5)
>
> Main clues:
>
> - These *statues* are wonderful!  I'm going to *invest* in the sculptor.
> - *Move faster*! I need to finish the 18th hole and return this *golf club* before noon.
>
> Additional clues related to clue #2, sorted by importance:
>
> - Our band's music is *testosterone* fueled.  We will be *more iconic than Nirvana*!
> - I'm trying to *move faster* but I need to do it *in a smart way*.
> - Keep your head down!  Our enemy *relishes* the chance to *take a pot shot* at us.
> - When I put on my wizard hat, my *clothes* make me look *disheveled and tired*.
> - I'm *not joking*!  You'd better not *get in my way*.
> - I love *the sound of making money*.
> - The last time I watched the *Winter Olympics was over 20 years ago*.
>
> Seven more clues related to clue #2:
>
> - Oops I broke your *sword in two*.  I have some *posters* of what it used to look like.
> - As a *person who baits sharks*, I can tell you that sharks love *cough drops* for some reason.
> - *Before sonar was invented*, we would get trapped in tight crevices in our submarine.  We would have to *push obstacles out of the way to escape*.
> - Did you know banshees *can kill a person* with their voice?  Better avoid their *greetings*.
> - My archaeological dig found *dental twine made of otter pelts*, and a *drinking mug* made of a skull.
> - My son has a *passion* for books.  I bought him a *reading system that he got hooked on* when he was young.
> - I love eating whole chickens.  I have a *gizzard phobia* though.
>
> Who / what am I?

<s>Hunt</s> Hint:

> Each clue can be <s>shelved</s> solved on its own.  Solving any one clue can lead to the final answer.  After getting the final answer, solving the <s>rust</s> rest of the clues should be <s>macho</s> much easier.

Hint 2:

> I recommend trying to solve clue #2.  In my opinion, it is the easiest of the clues and will unlock all the other clues when you figure it out.  In the meantime I added some italics to all the clues to make them easier to solve.

Hint 3:

> Clue #1 is not like the others.  Do that one last.  I modified clue #2 and added italics to it.  I also added 8 more clues and grouped them into 3 groups.  It's only a matter of time before someone gets it now.  The final answer should be a person who is known for clue #1 and clue #2.  But I'm expecting a correct answer to solve each other clue as well.

<sub>Previous puzzles in this series: [#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85513/i-make-billions) [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85557/i-make-billions-2) [#3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85634/i-make-billions-3) [#4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85674/i-make-billions-4)</sub>

Comment: [rot13]Fzryyf yvxr ovgpbva/pbva/zrgny/zrqny[/rot13]

Comment: Should this include the knowledge tag?

Comment: @Mohirl I don't know, I thought most of the [rot13]Uneel Cbggre[/rot13] references were quite well known.  I'm not sure where the line is between common knowledge and obscure knowledge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I've cracked it... I believe the answer is:

> JK Rowling, author of the Harry Potter series

Since:

> All of the clues from #2 onwards point towards words which sound like misspellings of character names and book titles in the Harry Potter series.

In particular, clue #2 "*Move faster*! I need to finish the 18th hole and return this *golf club* before noon." gives us:

> HURRY and PUTTER --> HARRY POTTER

Other clues resolve as follows:

> 3. Our band's music is *testosterone* fueled. We will be *more iconic than Nirvana*! = HORMONE and GRUNGIER --> HERMIONE GRANGER
>  4. I'm trying to *move faster* but I need to do it *in a smart way*. = RUN and WISELY --> RON WEASLEY
>  5. Keep your head down! Our enemy *relishes* the chance to *take a pot shot* at us. = SAVOURS and SNIPE --> SEVERUS SNAPE
>  6. When I put on my wizard hat, my *clothes* make me look *disheveled and tired*. = ROBES and HAGGARD --> RUBEUS HAGRID
>  7. I'm *not joking*! You'd better not *get in my way*. = SERIOUS and BLOCK --> SIRIUS BLACK
>  8. I love *the sound of making money*. = CHER-CHING --> CHO CHANG
>  9. The last time I watched *the Winter Olympics was over 20 years ago*. = NAGANO --> NAGINI

Section 3:

> ('Harry Potter and the...' book titles):
>  10. Oops I *broke your sword in two*. I have some *posters* of what it used to look like. = HALF-BLADE and PRINTS --> HALF-BLOOD PRINCE
>  11. As *a person who baits sharks*, I can tell you that sharks love *cough drops* for some reason. = CHUMMER and SUCRETS --> CHAMBER OF SECRETS
>  12. *Before sonar was invented*, we would get trapped in tight crevices in our submarine. We would have to *push obstacles out of the way to escape*. = PRE-SONAR and SOKOBAN (look it up!) --> PRISONER OF AZKABAN
>  13. Did you know banshees *can kill a person* with their voice? Better avoid their *greetings*. = DEADLY and HELLO'S --> DEATHLY HALLOWS
>  14. My archaeological dig found *dental twine made of otter pelts*, and a *drinking mug* made of a skull. = FLOSS OF FUR and STEIN --> PHILOSOPHER'S STONE
>  15. My son has a *passion* for books. I bought him *a reading system that he got hooked on* when he was young. = ARDOUR and PHONICS --> ORDER OF THE PHOENIX
>  16. I love eating whole chickens. I have a *gizzard phobia* though. = GIBLET and FEAR --> GOBLET OF FIRE

Returning to clue #1 (These *statues* are wonderful! I'm going to *invest* in the sculptor.), this gives:

> BUSTS and FUND --> FANTASTIC *BEASTS* AND WHERE TO *FIND* THEM. This is another of JK Rowling's series set in the Wizarding World.

This all fits with the theme since:

> Rowling's Harry Potter and Fantastic Beasts franchises have made billions from the sale of books and the accompanying movie series.

Comment: *Damn* ... I'd just figured out the theme, scrolled down to post it, and found your answer. Congrats and +1 :-)

Comment: Ah, sorry @Randal'Thor! It hit me with a similar 'aha' moment today... Any suggestions for improving the answer for clue #1 would be welcome - I'm not convinced I have that one exactly right yet...

Comment: @JS1 Ah yes - rot13(fbxbona!)

Comment: @JS1 It wouldn't happen to be rot13(snagnfgvp OHFGF naq jurer gb SHAQ gurz) by any chance??

Comment: Ok everything now looks correct except you switched up the pun word and the last name of the Ron character.  I also don't know what is wrong with your spoiler tags but if I have time later I'll try to edit.

Comment: Sigh. It's been a loooong day! And my seemingly-correct spoiler tags seem to break with a frustrating regularity and I can never work out how to fix them! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> Eagle/Eagles?

Move faster! I need to finish the 18th hole before noon.

> Eagle is a term in golf

I love the sound of making money.

> Refers to the bald eagle being on American currency.

Keep your head down! Our enemy relishes the chance to take a pot shot at us.

> This could be duck=Keep your head down, and duck being the enemy of the eagle (sort of).

Our band's music is testosterone fueled. We will be more iconic than Nirvana!

> Refers to The Eagles

The last time I watched the Winter Olympics was over 20 years ago.

> Has to be Eddie the Eagle who took part in the 1988 Winter Olympics.

Comment: @JS1 So the answer makes bullions, balloons, and billions?

Comment: @Duck You're being too literal.  There is the wordplay tag involved.  See hint 2.

Answer (score 1):

An extra hint from the author :

> When I wrote in chat "noon : moon, soon, goon, naan, nein, noun "(replacing the word noon from the second clue) JS1 , the author said "Hey you are getting the right idea."

Final guess and them I am really done

> Harley Davidson

I need to finish the 18th hole before noon

> Hole can be rearranged to HarLEy and it was the only thing I could find that makes sense

Makes Billions

> Harley makes billions of motorcycles each year

Comment: There's actually a lot more to this puzzle than meets the eye.  When the answer is revealed, all will make sense.  I'll add a hint because people seem to be on the wrong track.

Comment: @JS1 Is the Title a clue

Comment: @AgentLu You should look at the other 4 puzzles, they all relate to "I make billions" in some way.  For this puzzle, the fact that "bullions" and "balloons" are crossed out is a clue.

Comment: @JS1 Keeps suggesting some wordplay with the crossed out words, which none of the answers have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95684/discussion-between-agent-lu-and-duck).

Comment: @JS1 I have a new answer. Is this getting closer to the right answer?

Comment: Sorry Harley Davidson is not right.

Answer (score 1):

Totally wild guess, but maybe:

> Nagano, Japan?

These statues are wonderful! I'm investing in the sculptor.

> There are Buddhist sculptures.

Move faster! I need to finish the 18th hole before noon.

> There are also some golf courses.

The last time I watched the Winter Olympics was over 20 years ago.

> They hosted the Winter Olympics in 1998.

Most likely being too literal, but these clues line up well.

Comment: Sorry not the right answer. Needs more wordplay/lateral thinking/understanding what the struck out words have to do with it. I think when you see the final answer, you will either think "Oh I get it now (light bulb moment)" or "too obscure, there's no way I could have thought of that". I'm hoping more people will see it the first way than the second.  I made this puzzle harder on purpose because the last two in this series were solved within 30 minutes, which is no fun.

Answer (score 0):

My new guess:

> Bull market

From the title:

> bullions -> bull

These statues are wonderful! I'm investing in the sculptor.

> Famous statue of a bull in front of NYSE, also investing -> bull market

I'm moving as fast as I can! I need to work smarter, not harder.

> Bull trying to gore someone, but only goes straight and isn't too smart about it

I'm not joking! You'd better not get in my way.

> If you get in a bull's way... life won't last too long for you.

I love the sound of making money.

> Definition of a bull market again

Keep your head down! Our enemy relishes the chance to take a pot shot at us.

> Bulls charge with their heads down

"Macho"

> Bullfighters, in a word.

Comment: Sorry that's not it.

Comment: @JS1 is this right by any chance?

Comment: Sorry not bull.