# I make billions (#6)

Tags: connect-wall

#### I make billions (#6)

This is a two part [connect wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connect-wall) puzzle.  The sixteen words should be arranged into four groups of four words, with each group's words related to each other by a common theme.  The four group names can then be used to find the final answer.

```
    box     farm    fire    flat
    games   giant   hill    monkey  
    pig     queen   roll    space
    tire    vein    wing    wolf
```

Hint for after you solve the groups:

> Although the group names might relate to a man, the answer should be the name of a company.

<sub>Previous puzzles in this series: [#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85513/i-make-billions) [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85557/i-make-billions-2) [#3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85634/i-make-billions-3) [#4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85674/i-make-billions-4) [#5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85725/i-make-billions-5)</sub>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I reckon the wall can be resolved as follows:

> X = Box, Games, Wing, Space (Xbox, the X Games, X-wing from Star Wars, and SpaceX);
> ANT = Farm, Queen, Hill, Fire (ant farm, queen ant, anthill, fire ant);
> IRON = Pig, Flat, Giant, Tire (pig iron, flatiron, The Iron Giant, tire iron);
> SPIDER = Monkey, Wolf, Roll, Vein (spider monkey, wolf spider, spider roll (sushi), spider vein).

These 4 can of course be resolved with:

> MAN (X-man, Ant-Man, Iron Man, Spider-Man)

Since these are all:

> Characters in the Marvel franchise as created by Stan Lee et al.

Meaning the company in the final answer is:

> MARVEL, a company which not only makes movies which rake in more than a billion dollars, but sometimes also feels like they make a billion movies!

Comment: Thanks for fixing the spoiler tag @OmegaKrypton! Sometimes I can never seem to get that '>!' tag to hold!

Comment: welcome Stiv :) +1 & happy puzzling

Comment: Excellent job!  Well done!