# Mirror Mirror on the wall, who's the richest of them all? (I make billions #7)

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

#### *Mirror Mirror* on the wall, who's the richest of them all? (I make billions #7)

**Clue group 1:**

- This spa provides a great *relaxation rub.  Earbuds* are included too.
- I compared virtual machines, and *oddly Dalvik nipped* JVM by only a hair.
- What's this sight I'm seeing? Rapunzel and Flynn arguing?
- I'm Agent Johnson.  This is Special Agent Johnson. No relation. <sub>[(Watch this if you don't get the joke)](https://youtu.be/HY_nkgJG3oE)</sub>

**Clue group 2:**

- My favorite cartoon character is Bojack Horseman.  If that horse got injured, would he go to the hospital or to the vets?
- There are some people who think Santa Claus is *evil*.  *Really, no joking*!
- I need to get my cuckoo clock fixed, time permitting.

Who / What am I?

**Notes:**

1. The answer is not literally the richest in the world.
2. The first clue has some italicization to provide a hint.  After each day that the puzzle is not solved, I will italicize an additional clue.
3. The video link for clue #4 has nothing to do with the puzzle.  It's just there in case you've never seen Die Hard.

<sub>Previous puzzles in this series: [#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85513/i-make-billions) [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85557/i-make-billions-2) [#3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85634/i-make-billions-3) [#4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85674/i-make-billions-4) [#5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85725/i-make-billions-5) [#6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85920/i-make-billions-6)</sub>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it! You are

> Apple, the multinational tech. company

Each clue in group 1

> Contains the name of a variety of *apple* hidden backwards among its letters, often spanning multiple words

Like so:

> This spa provides a great relaxatio**n rub. Earb**uds are included too. = BRAEBURN
>  I compared virtual machines, and oddl**y Dal**vi**k nip**ped JVM by only a hair. = PINK LADY
>  What's this sig**ht I'm s**eeing? Rapunzel and Fl**ynn arg**uing? = GRANNY SMITH
>  I'm Agent Johnson. This is Speci**al Ag**ent Johnson. No relation. = GALA

Meanwhile, each clue in group 2

> Contains the name of Apple founders / board members, etc.

Like so:

> My favorite cartoon character i**s Boj**ack Horseman. If that horse got injured, would he go to the hospital or to th**e vets**? = STEVE JOBS
>  There are some people who think Santa Claus is **evi**l. Reall**y, no j**oking! = JONY IVE
>  I need to get my cuc**koo c**lock fixed, time per**mit**ting. = TIM COOK

All this considered, it is now evident that the title was a clue to this since

> The use of ‘Mirror, Mirror...’ points to the evil queen from Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs, who attempts to poison Snow White with… an apple!

And

> It doubled as a hint towards the method required to decipher the puzzle: reading backwards, as if the clues were reflected in a mirror... (pointed out by Omega Krypton in the comments)

Comment: and title refers to reading stuff like looking in a mirror (reversed direction). well done +1

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Ah yes, true! Ha, funny - that didn't even strike me!

Comment: Very good explanation! Actually the "mirror mirror" title was a hint to read the clues in reverse, but the "Snow White" connection actually fits really well and I wish I had thought of that too!

Comment: @JS1 Haha! So just a happy coincidence then! Funny... :-)